# Woocommerce: changing user role when order is complete

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, roles

I'm using wordpress with woocommerce, and I would like to automate the following step. When an order is completed, I would like to change the user role associated  with that order id from 'customer' to 'subscriber'.

By searching around, I think I should be able to accomplish this by using a hook in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'change_role_from_customer_to_subscriber' );
```

Then add the function:

```
function change_role_from_customer_to_subscriber($order_id){
// code to change role to subscriber
}
```

In the code, I think I need to do 2 things:
1) get the user id that is associated with that order id
2) change role of that user id to subscriber

I've tried a lot, but I couldn't get it to work (neither getting the right user id, nor changing the role of a user id). So any help would be appreciated! I've seen 2 related questions asked before on stack overflow, but unfortunately the answers there did not work for me. I hope someone can help me out!

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helgatheviking from wordpress answers came up with this piece of code:

```
function wpa_120656_convert_paying_customer( $order_id ) {

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

if ( $order->user_id > 0 ) {
    update_user_meta( $order->user_id, 'paying_customer', 1 );
    $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

    // Remove role
    $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); 

    // Add role
    $user->add_role( 'subscriber' );
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wpa_120656_convert_paying_customer' );
```

For some unknown reason it took several tries, but it worked! Thanks everyone for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
$user_data = array(
            'ID' => $current_user->ID,
            'role' => 'New Role Here' 
        );
wp_update_user( $user_data );
```

Add this to your above function, and it will do the trick.

Comment: Well, I did manage to change the user role... unfortunately it changed mine so now I'm a subscriber instead of an admin :P
It should be easy to fix (I have backup account), but I need to combine your code with a way to get the right user data (I need the user who posted the order in woocommerce). Anyway, thank you! I'm one step closer and it feels like a victory, haha!

Comment: The above will do this... It grabs the id of the current user, and then will update accordingly.

Comment: But then, if I would flag the order of another user as complete, then this code would change my role and thus making me a subscriber...