# Woocommerce default role and role after purchase

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, registration, roles

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681523/woocommerce-changing-user-role-when-order-is-complete) but it doesn't exactly do what I'm looking for.

My question is, how can I change the default Woocommerce role "customer" to, e.g. "Subscriber" for new registered users. 
And then, if user checks out (purchases product), change the role from "Subscriber" to "Customer".

I'm asking this as I want to show different content per user roles: "registered customer" and "subscribed (paid) customer".

Comment: Only suggestion... If you want to show or hide content only not product, I will highly suggest you to use Paid Memberships Pro https://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/ instead of woocommerce.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your question is changing the default role of user that is created by WooCommerce. Honestly, I'd probably leave the default role as customer. And then create a new role/capability for people who purchase your specific product.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_customer_data', 'so_29647785_default_role' );

function so_29647785_default_role( $data ){
    $data['role'] = 'subscriber'; // the new default role
    return $data;
}
```

As you saw in my other answer (well my re-posted answer), you can do things once the user has finished paying, but hooking into the `woocommerce_order_status_completed` hook.

To adapt that code to do something specific to a particular product, you need to loop through the order items and check them against a product ID. Replace 999 with the ID of the product in question.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'so_29647785_convert_customer_role' );

function so_29647785_convert_customer_role( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if ( $order->user_id > 0 ) {

        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $order_item ) {

            if( 999 == $order_item[ 'product_id' ] ) {
                $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

                // Remove existing role
                $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); 

                // Add new role
                $user->add_role( 'subscriber' );        
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Note: Totally untested, but seems right in theory.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I will test this on my site. About changing the default role to "Subscriber". You're right, it would make sense to keep the default role "customer" as it is, and then create a new role, e.g. "paid customer" for the checkout users.